# Template assignment function for packed struct member

Tags: c++, templates

How to write a template function to implement such **template assignment for packed struct member** ?

In my project, a template assignemnt function is used to avoid various implicit conversion problems. The code is like below

```
template<typename LHS, typename RHS> inline LHS &assign(LHS &lhs, RHS rhs) {
    return lhs = static_cast<LHS>(rhs);
}

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    long b = 0;
    a = b;  // warning if -Wconversion enabled
    assign(a, b); // no warning 
}
```

This works fine. But recently, I needed to add `packed struct` in my code and assign value to the memeber. The template assign function didn't work any more.

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) Data
{
    int m;
    int n;
};

template<typename LHS, typename RHS> inline LHS &assign(LHS &lhs, RHS rhs) {
    return lhs = static_cast<LHS>(rhs);
}

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    long b = 0;
    Data d;
    assign(a, b);  // works fine 
    assign(d.m, a);  // error: cannot bind packed field ‘d.Data::m’ to ‘int&’
}
```

Comment: The whole point of the warning is to make you think about a potentially dangerous cast. Either change the types of variables so there isn't a type mismatch or explicitly cast it `d.m = static_cast<int>(b);`. Or instead of hiding the cast in the `assign` function, turn off the warning

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a non-const reference to a bitfield (and `__attribute__((packed))` essentially makes a bit field out of `int m` member variable).

You can, however, pass the object as a whole and assign the bitfield inside of this assignment operation:

```cpp
struct __attribute__((packed)) Data
{
    int m;
    
    Data(int value): m{ value } {}
};

template<typename LHS, typename RHS> inline LHS &assign(LHS &lhs, const RHS& rhs) {
    return lhs = static_cast<LHS>(rhs);
}

int main() {
    Data d{ 2 };
    long b = 0;
    // static_cast<Data>(b) actually creates a temporary and assigns it to the Data object
    assign(d, b);
    return d.m;
}
```

Comment: Thx for replying, but my actual Data has more than one member, this method doesn't apply.

Comment: @LinfengMu it doesn't matter. The restrictions and solution still hold: you cannot change a bitifield via a reference, but you can handle it yourself in the copy constructor or custom assignment operator. Also you may want to edit your question and adjust the MRE so it better reflects your limitations